# How do copy a modify field of a table to a new field in the same table?

Tags: sql, mysql

I have a MySQL database table `C` with a field called `Phone`. I've already created a new field in the `C` table called `PhoneFixed` and I want to update that field with a modified version of the `Phone` field.

The `PhoneFixed` field will use the following statement to get its value:

```
Concat('(',Left(C.Phone,3),') ',Right(C.Phone,8)) As `PhoneFixed`
```

What statement do I need to automatically update the value of `PhoneFixed` to be equal to the result of the statement above for all rows in my table?

Comment: When you say "create a new field" are you saying you want to update an existing column *value* in the table or alter the table to create a new column?

Comment: I should have clarified.  I've already added that field to my db table.  I just need to update the data that's in that field.  I'm not sure how to form the SQL statement to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to update a pre-existing `PhoneFixed` column for all rows, you'd run a query like this:

```
UPDATE C
SET PhoneFixed = CONCAT('(', LEFT(Phone, 3), ') ', RIGHT(Phone, 8))
```

Comment: Perfect, thanks! I always forget the syntax for updating tables.  I'm so used to running `Select` all the time, I rarely need to remember everything else.

Comment: Correct, but the concat is actually wrong for USA phone numbers ... you would probably want CONCAT('(', LEFT(Phone, 3), ') ', RIGHT(Phone, 7))

Comment: well, the `Phone` field is currently stored as `XXX-XXX-XXXX`, so the `Right(Phone, 8)` takes into account the hyphen.  I just need to format this correctly so I can join it to a main table in our system's database.

Answer (score 1):

If I understood you correctly, a simple UPDATE will work:

```
UPDATE C SET PhoneFixed = CONCAT('(', LEFT(Phone, 3), ') ', RIGHT(Phone, 8))
```

That will update the PhoneFixed using the Phone value from the same row.